# How do you use Ping & Pong in Alchemy Websockets?

Tags: c#, websocket, alchemy-websockets

I am using [Alchemy Websockets](http://alchemywebsockets.net/) And looking at the source code, it has Ping/Pong support, but there doesn't seem to be a way of using it.

I want to send a Ping from the server at a timed interval, and if I don't get a reply from the client, close the connection down.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is built-in:

```
var aServer = new WebSocketServer(81, IPAddress.Any) {
    OnReceive = OnReceive,
    OnSend = OnSend,
    OnConnect = OnConnect,
    OnConnected = OnConnected,
    OnDisconnect = OnDisconnect,
    TimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
  };
```

That `TimeOut` parameter seems to be the key. **Probably** pings are being sent each TimeOut/3 or TimeOut/2 interval, and if a connection does not answer one in TimeOut, will get disconnect it.

You can see the ping/pong frames from Google Chrome. Open the network tab, select the WebSocket connection (the one with HTTP 101 status) and open the Frames tab (that tab does not autorefresh, so you have to switch in time to time).

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.  Looking the the source code, the TimeOut parameter does not seem to be hooked up to anything.  I guess it was never implemented.

Comment: What a pity. I maintain a WebSocket component for .NET and Mono. Ping works :D . It scales better than Alchemy, you may want to give it a try: http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/

Comment: It would be nice if yours had a websocket client as well.  I needed both for my app.  It's hard to changeover now, but something to look at in the future, thanks.

Comment: Any client would work, does not need to be from the same "vendor". Anyway, if you find how to make the ping work please update this post, I am interested as well.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I tried the one client built into Mono, but it doesn't work.  I submitted a bug report, detailing exactly which bit of code was wrong, but then I ran unto other problems, so abandoned it, and went with Alchemy.  On paper at least, it did everything I wanted.  But that's buggy too.

Comment: Now that you mention it... yes, client implementations are not very good. I remember one that failed if your host name has two subdomains or more like proxy.connect.whatever.com because a regular expression (I think it was Alchemy actually). It may be worth to do one.